# Net:IMAP speed and performance advice

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, imap

I am using Mikel's mail https://github.com/mikel/mail ruby gem to read from an IMAP server.

It all works great however I was wondering if you guys know a way to speed up SEARCH command requests.

A simple query such as:

```
Mail.find(:what => :last, :count => 2, :order => :desc, :keys => ['FROM', 'Jim Smith'])
```

Seems to take a while to request. Can I do this in a quicker way or improve my query in any way? Average load time for this query is about 10-30 seconds.

Any help, if any, would be appreciated.

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing much that can be done at client end. It has to be the IMAP server who should respond with desired data quickly. In case the mailbox of user is big, it might take a longer time to search for strings.

The query that you are hitting is going to check all the mails(['FROM', 'Jim Smith']) for users mailbox so definitely a longer time.